# Select maximum date with group by another columns

Tags: mysql, count, group-by

I have a table like:

**gold_2012**

```
gold_city | gold_type | gold_cost | gold_selltime
--------------------------------------------------
city1     | type 1    | 41.23     | 2012-01-01   
city1     | type 1    | 42.23     | 2012-02-02   
city1     | type 1    | 40.23     | 2012-03-03   
city2     | type 2    | 43.23     | 2012-01-01   
city2     | type 2    | 45.23     | 2012-02-02   
city2     | type 2    | 47.23     | 2012-03-03   
city3     | type 3    | 48.23     | 2012-01-01   
city3     | type 3    | 49.23     | 2012-02-02   
city3     | type 3    | 44.23     | 2012-03-03
```

How can I get 1 last result order by `gold_selltime` desc each group by `gold_city` and `gold_type`.

I used this:

```
SELECT * , COUNT( * ) 
FROM  gold_2012
GROUP BY  gold_type ,  gold_city
ORDER BY gold_selltime DESC
```

but it didn't work.
I only have result like:

```
gold_city | gold_type | gold_cost | gold_selltime
--------------------------------------------------
city1     | type 1    | 41.23     | 2012-01-01   
city2     | type 2    | 43.23     | 2012-01-01   
city3     | type 3    | 48.23     | 2012-01-01
```

but I need it like:

```
gold_city | gold_type | gold_cost | gold_selltime
--------------------------------------------------
city1     | type 1    | 40.23     | 2012-03-03   
city2     | type 2    | 47.23     | 2012-03-03   
city3     | type 3    | 44.23     | 2012-03-03
```

Sorry! I forget sth! Please see my edited question above.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use [`MAX`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_max) function for that:

```
SELECT gold_city, gold_type 
       , MAX(gold_selltime) AS gold_selltime, COUNT( * ) AS `COUNT`
FROM gold_2012 
GROUP BY gold_type , gold_city 
ORDER BY gold_selltime DESC
```

#### [See this SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!8/22fba/2)

Note: You can convert your date using [`DATE_FORMAT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) function:

```
DATE_FORMAT(MAX(gold_selltime), '%Y-%m-%d') AS gold_selltime
```

#### [See this SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!8/22fba/4)

### UPDATE

<sup>As OP changed his/her requirement see this updated answer:</sup>

You can achieve that using the following query:

```
SELECT *
FROM gold_2012
WHERE gold_selltime IN
(
    SELECT MAX(gold_selltime) AS gold_selltime
    FROM gold_2012  
)
```

#### [See this SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!8/22fba/10)

Comment: Thanks for answer! Your sql work without gold_cost collumn. But if like my question edited above, I didn't work.

Comment: @quanganh_developer Updated the answer. Note that always show your actual requirement because if you don't show your actual req., the given answer may not satisfy what you want as it happen not.

Comment: I'm so sorry about my mistake

Comment: @quanganh_developer Please don't apology. I just told you that updating question may make a good answer invalid :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
SELECT gold_city,gold_type , MAX(gold_selltime)
FROM gold
WHERE gold_city IN (select distinct gold_city from gold) 
GROUP BY gold_city ,gold_type
```

Comment: it was a typo sorry! i was testing with my testtable

Comment: @hims056 :would you please remove the downvote,its a working example

Comment: You don't need to add `WHERE gold_city IN (select distinct gold_city from gold)` when you are grouping it(`gold_city`). [See this](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!8/22fba/9)

Comment: Yes,you are correct!But my understanding was that an answer receives a downvote if it is irrelevant or unsuccessfully in its methodology. Anyway i will thumbs up your query only rather than mine as it does in more cleaner way :)

Comment: The main reason is: why to use extra `WHERE` when we can achieve that without using it?